# React js how to trigger an event to another div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a swiper overlay that I would like to close by clicking a close button but i don't know how to do it. I tried to use refs and adding a class to a function to close it but it doesn't work. In general I don't know how to trigger an event to another div in react. Could someone help me?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../styles/Swiper.css';
import '../styles/SwiperGraphic.css';

export default class SwiperComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

}

closeSwiper() {
     //add a class
}

render(){

    let swiperDiv = this.refs.SwiperDiv;

    const params = {

        rebuildOnUpdate : true,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        grabCursor: true,
        direction: 'horizontal',

      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: true,

      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
      },
      spaceBetween: 100
    }

    return(
        <div ref={this.refs.swiperDiv}>
            <Swiper {...params} key={this.props.slides.length} >
                 {this.props.slides.map((slide) =>{
                        return <div><Image responsive className={(slide.w == '600' ? 'swiperImg600Padding' : 'null')} src={slide.url} slide={slide} key={slide.tit} width={slide.w} height={slide.h} /></div>
                    })}
            </Swiper>

            <div className="swiper-close-button" onClick={this.closeSwiper.bind(this)}><Image src="/assets/img/close-swiper-graphic.svg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

}

Comment: hey just to clarify , do you want to hide/remove the <Swiper> component ?

Comment: no just want to hide/show with display:none

Comment: its still unclear what you want to hide , you want this whole component  which is used in some parent component right ?

Comment: i want to hide the whole component  (swiper + close button) with a css animation, no need to remove it and recreate it

Comment: "no need to remove it and recreate it" - this is one of the core tenets of React. You're trying to use the framework outside the general limits of it's design purpose and making things difficult and confusing in the process.

Comment: eurobob removing and recreating the swiper will solve?

Comment: Yes, but this should probably be done in the parent component relative to this one, as you will probably also wish to only show the close button when the swiper is visible

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you could approach this, but effectively you want to conditionally render the swiper with a boolean value in your component state.

So your code might end up looking like this, but this is not exactly the most elegant way to deal with this, and you probably want to be toggling the rendering of SwiperComponent from the parent component where you are calling it from:

```
export default class SwiperComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: true
    }
}

closeSwiper() {
  this.setState({
    isOpen: false
  })
}

render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.isOpen &&
            <Swiper />
        }
      </div>
    )

}
}
```

That being said, your implementation shows that you don't really understand how to use React properly yet, and you are still thinking in jQuery practices with class toggling etc., so I recommend you read the documentation some more and go through the tutorial to understand how to leverage the power of state.

Comment: Good call, my answer showed how to use a ref like he wanted to, but you're right that he probably shouldn't use a ref for this in the first place.

Comment: Even i thought the same , but wanted to clarify the use case, basically hide/show should depend on prop , the parent state should decide whether to show it or not.
Once its removed , the only way to open it to re-create the component.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the ref in the constructor using React.createRef, (not in the render function) set it on the div, and then you can reference it in your handler function with .current, and then you can do whatever you need to with it:

```
export default class SwiperComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.swiperRef = React.createRef();
    }

    closeSwiper() {
         //add a class
        this.swiperRef.current.doWhateverYouWantToIt();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div ref={this.refs.swiperDiv}>
                <Swiper {...params} key={this.props.slides.length} >
                   {Stuff}
                </Swiper>
                <div className="swiper-close-button"
                    onClick= {() => this.closeSwiper()}
                >
                    {Stuff}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Edit: on another note, binding within the render function is usually considered no good practice, consider doing it in the constructor, or use an arrow function, and as Atul pointed out, looks like you maybe have the wrong function name there?

Comment: where is this toggleSwiper function ?

Comment: That came from his example code. You're probably right that he meant that to be the closeSwiper function

Comment: I edited the question toggleSwiper is closeSwiper sorry for mistake

Answer (score 0):

so basically if you want to hide the whole component , you must be using it in parent like

import SwiperComponent  from '/path to swipercomponent'

```
//bind this in constructor
changeSwiperState(showSwiper) {
    this.setState({showSwiper})
  }
render(){
    const style = this.state.showSwiper? {}:{display:'none'};
    return (
        <div style={style}>
           <SwiperComponent changeSwiperState={changeSwiperState}/>
        </div>
    )

}
```

call the function from the swiper component on button click like

```
<div className="swiper-close-button" onClick={this.props.changeSwiperState(false)}></div>
```

So no you can always toggle the modal , as the show/hide control is with parent.

Good luck !